# How to remove jQuery codes from page?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to remove or delete all jQuery codes from page in codebehind?
First I want to delete all and then recreate some of them.

Comment: I would rather omit the adding in the first place than try some quirky method to remove them later on.

Comment: how you are adding jquery code you are refering to on the page ?

Comment: What do you mean by "jQuery codes"? jQuery is just a Javascript library, so what you have in the page is just some Javascript code that uses jQuery.

Comment: For ex I have this code. I wrote it to page. <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#MainContent_fileUpload').live('change', function () {
            $("#MainContent_btnUpload").click();
        }); But in cs i need to remove it.

Comment: you cannot delete it unless  it is a server tag with runat server attribute

Comment: Probably you're right but we can add new jquery with stringbuilder and append function from codebehing. If we can add i think we can also remove it too. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are thinking about this the wrong way, you don't need to remove the code just add a condition that means it only runs when you want it to.
For example you could add a class to the element you want to affect with your jQuery and only run the click function if it has this class. When you don't want it to run remove the class, when you do want it to run add the class.... simple.

```
$('#MainContent_fileUpload').live('change', function () { 
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){ 
        $("#MainContent_btnUpload").click(); 
    }
});

if (condition of acivity){
    $('#MainContent_fileUpload').addClass('active')
}

if (condition of inacivity){
    $('#MainContent_fileUpload').removeClass('active')
}
```

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the only way.